# want to login in laravel passport multiauth

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-authentication

here how i can pass my new guard name is trainer

```
if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
$token = auth()->user()->createToken('TutsForWeb')->accessToken;
return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
} else {
return response()->json(['error' => 'UnAuthorised'], 401);
}
```

here I am using

```
 'Auth::guard('trainer')->attempt($credentials)'
```

but it show Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.

i am using this code 
https://github.com/tusharkhan/Laravel-Passport-MultiAuth/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/PassportController.php

Answer (score 1):

Actually,
The attempt method is part of the SessionGuard you cannot use Passport, and attempt to log in a user, Passport is used for API authentication, and APIs typically use tokens to authenticate users and do not maintain session state between requests.

To make it work change your driver for the trainer guard to session like this

```
'trainer' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'trainers',// Your trainer table name here
],
```

Comment: but I have to work with passport auth so what I have to replace with attempt

Comment: @Manojkumar follow this link https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/161#issuecomment-299690583 to get the more information